# How to create a SQL database within VB.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am currently creating a vb.net program in which users upload a song file to the program and then it is saved within the programs files. I have set up the actual saving of the files but would also like to store some meta data of each in a SQL database within my program.

I have looked online and although i now understand the basics of SQL, im still a little fuzzy on how you actually implement this within VB.net. I have already added the library- `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` but failed to work out how to begin coding in SQL.

The basics of what im trying to acheive is a if statement that will determine wether or not a SQL database has been created in a specific location, and if it hasnt it should create it.

All constructive answers appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " wether or not a SQL database has been created in a specific location"

Comment: If database already exists it should not try to create a new one

Comment: Which database product will you be using?

Comment: I dont follow you..

Comment: @Lupe_99 - Are you using SQLite, SQL Server, MySql, Mongo, RavenDB, FoxPro, dBase, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different database engines available.  The namespace that you have chosen contains the ADO.NET client classes for Microsoft SQL Server.  You would use a connection string to specify how to connect to the database.  This would often contain connection information, such as server name, user name, password etc, but it sounds like you want to store data locally.

There is a local version of SQL Server called LocalDB, but I think you would still need quite a lot of the SQL Server components installed for that to work.  Although you can package these with your application they may be too large for you, so you may want to look at SQL Server Compact Edition, which is much smaller and allows you to package the whole engine as part of your application and is useful for storing data locally.  Compact edition doesn't have quite all of the features that LocalDB does, so you may want to compare the features available for each.

Although you can use the ADO.NET objects to connect to a database, I think most people these days would use a layer on top which transfers data back and forwards between objects in memory and the database.  This also allows you to use Linq to query the database in most cases.  I personally use Entity Framework.  You might want to look into that.  There are different ways of configuring EF so you may want to look at a tutorial.  Once you have it set up, you will probably find it much easier and safer to work with than writing SQL manually though.